# get href attribute of enclosing link tag

Tags: jquery, parent, attr

Having a little trouble on this one. I need a way using Jquery/JS to find the HREF attribute of the enclosing link tag:

```
<a href="something.html"><img src="img1.jpg" class="active"></a>
```

I want to target the img by class and find the value of the 1st preceding href attribute.

```
$("img.active").somethingAwesome().attr("href");
```

Please show me somethingAwesome() ...help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$("img.active").parent("a").attr("href")` will get the direct parent's href attribute, assuming it's an anchor. If there's any depth of containing blocks between the image and the anchor, use instead `$("img.active").closest("a").attr("href")`.

Comment: +1 for using closest rather than parent. This makes it safer for refactoring and there is no difference in performance.

Comment: awesome! thanks. Such a noob question. Figured it would be as easy. Good old Jquery.

Comment: As a side question, does closest search up or down the document. If it checks both up and down for closest, then closest is too unpredictable.

Comment: @3Dom .closest searches upward for ancestors. If you would like to find descendants, you'll want to go with [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: thank bodeaux that really helps for a noob like myself. please feel free to bask in the glory of being the smartest guy in my class. My theory for the day: A question well asked is a question half answered.

Comment: if ($(img.active").parent("a")){ var $parent="mother"; var $found = (this).attr("href"); } else { var $parent="trailorTrash"; var $found = $(this).closest("a").attr("href");};

Answer (score 3):

`.parent()` is all you need!

```
$("img.active").parent().attr("href");
```

[Here is the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) :)

As per Kyle's comment, and in an attempt to make something as robust as possible, you could try:

```
$("img.active").closest('a[href]').attr("href");
```

that way, even if your html looks like this:

```
<a href="something.html">
    <a name="anchor">
        <img src="img1.jpg" class="active">
    </a>
</a>
```

you'll still get what you need :)

Comment: This won't work if there is another element between the anchor and the image. closest() should be used.

Comment: he wants the "1st preceding href attribute"

Comment: yeah, okay, fair enough, that's a perfectly valid interpretation.  It's not 100% clear that the example is representative.  But if we assume it's not, then there are all kinds of other possible problems, too.  What if there's a `<a name=""></a>` element in between, for example?  `.closest('a')` will fail then too, and `.closest('a[href]')` will be required!

Comment: Understood. No harm intended.

Comment: @simon I think a more common usecase of an anchored image with a containing block between it and its ancestor would be `<a><span><img /></span></a>`. Nesting anchors creates a syntactically invalid context.

Comment: @lthibodeaux - that's certainly true.  I was assuming that the OP's use case was as he presented it.  If it's not, then all bets are off, of course :)

Comment: @simon Understood, and .parent() is certainly the most indicative of what's actually happening in the traversal in the OP's example DOM structure. I was simply referring to your edit with nested `<a><a>...</a></a>` tags.

Comment: @Kyle Kind of a misleading example. Like I said, anchor nesting is syntactically invalid: [see the reference document](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2). Would really suggest changing it.

Comment: thanks to all you folks for putting in such a heroic effort. What an awesome place this forum is. Searching up and down the document in a logical way was my main query. I would say the most important benefit of JS styling over CSS styling is the ability to change styles through an unrelated element. This is definitely the most powerful asset of JS.

Comment: you all answered correctly. Is there a tick for that? parent() will act if there is a parent. You can go up the document to nearest with closest() or down the document with find(). This traversal is what I was after at the end of the day.

Comment: @3Dom: no worries, I've got no problem with @lthibodeaux's answer being accepted -- it's correct, it's succinct, and he's right about the nested anchors being strictly invalid (seen it in the wild, though...).  Anyway, glad you got what you needed :)

Answer (score 0):

$("img.active").closest("a").attr("href");

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img.active").closest('a').attr("href");
```

Comment: what if I have multiple instances of my example code and only two of them have anchors? I want to find if the tag is wrapped in an HREF tag or not.

Comment: parent() is the best thing I've come across for this purpose, but all your comments have helped me immensely