# Use AJAX and THEN follow a link

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am having an issue with processing an AJAX function in jQuery and then following a link.  I have a function that runs on ANY click on a page like `jQuery('body').live('click', function(event) {});`

This event may or not be a link.   Within this callback I have something like `jQuery.post();` running.  So anytime a click event happens anywhere on the body this runs.  My issue occurs when this click is a link or some sort of div inside a link.  I have tried things like:

`event.preventDefault();`

followed by

`if ( jQuery(event.target).attr('href').length ) {
            var url = jQuery(event.target).attr('href');
            window.setTimeout(function(){document.location.href=url;}, 1000); // timeout and waiting until effect is complete
        }`

but the problem with this is that if you have something like `<a><div></div></a>` this will not work.  My question is....

Is there a reliable way to pause a link being followed, process AJAX, and then resume following the link?

Comment: Just find the closest enclosing link.

For details see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202619/get-href-attribute-of-enclosing-link-tag).

Comment: // Removed because of dumb comments.

Comment: I think he meant `jQuery(event.target).closest('a').attr('href').length ) { var url = jQuery(event.target).closest('a').attr('href'); window.setTimeout(function(){document.location.href=url;}, 1000); // timeout and waiting until effect is complete }`. Seems like it should work for you.

Comment: That is what he meant =).  And I just tested and it works great.  I removed my comment above when I realized this.  But, in case anyone reads this I left out the 'a' in the above code.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

```
$("a").live('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = this.href;
  setTimeout(function(){
    location.href = url;
  },1000);
});
```

I just wonder if this would affect any other wordpress plugins that may have anchor tags with events bound to them.

Edit: To add to this, you may also want to ensure that the request is to a different page:

```
$("a").live('click',function(e){
  var url = this.href;
  if (url == location.href) {
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();      
  setTimeout(function(){
    location.href = url;
  },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a hack, but it seems like you could change all your link targets to "#" and then create another attribute with the real target.  Catch the click event, process it, and then process the real target.  You should be able to do this all from jQuery/JavaScript code without editing your actual html.

Comment: Not just a hack, an atrocity ;)

Comment: I can't do this because I have no control over the page itself.  This is being used in a WP plugin and I am trying to keep it as general as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a fade (for example), you can then follow the link using a callback. But be sure to return false from your onclick handler, or you will navigate immediately:

```js
function onclickCallback() {
    $("#myelement").fadeOut(500, function() {
        window.location.href = "http://example.com/mynewpage";
    });
    return false;
}
```

And finally, call this with:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="onclickCallback()">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the bug about `jQuery(event.target).closest('a').attr('href').length is undefined`.  Just add this line of code in line 97 `if ( jQuery(event.target).closest('a').attr('href')) {` ..... See below it fixes the error:

```
    // Redirect if this is a link
    if ( jQuery(event.target).closest('a').attr('href')) {
        if ( jQuery(event.target).closest('a').attr('href').length ) {
            var url = jQuery(event.target).closest('a').attr('href');
            if ( jQuery(event.target).closest('a').attr('target') == '_blank') {
                window.setTimeout(function() 
                    { window.open(url, '_blank') },
                    window.name,
                    1000);
            } else {
                window.setTimeout(function(){document.location.href=url;}, 1000); // timeout and waiting until effect is complete 
            }           
        }
    }
```

Anyway, great plugin :)..