# C# variable passed as argument to onclick() is undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

I have a view `Details` which consists of a partial view `_Tabs` and a second partial view `_Contents`.

In one of the partial views (`_Tabs`), I have a image link, and in the `onclick` function, I'm passing a variable `CatID`. 
This variable contains the value of a property of the ViewModel of the partial view (called `TabsForItemViewModel`).

When debugging, when the image is clicked, VS displays:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'CatID' is undefined

**Partial View "_Tabs":**

View Model for the partial view `_Tabs` is `TabsForItemViewModel`

```
@model TabsForItemViewModel
@{
   int CatID = Model.CategoryInfo.CatID; 
 }

<ul>
<li>
   <a href="#GoToCatLevel">
     <img border="0" src="view_cat.png" alt ="Up" title="Go To This Category" 
          width="10" height="10" onclick="LoadCategoryData(CatID, this.href)" />
   </a>
</li>
...
```

**View "Details":**

```
@model ItemDetailsViewModel
@{    
    ViewBag.Title = "Item Details";
}

<div id="Main">
...
   CategoryInfoViewModel categoryData = new CategoryInfoViewModel(itemD.Ca_ID);                                                   

    TabsForItemViewModel tabsForItem = new TabsForItemViewModel(categoryData);
    <div id="Tabs" class="div-tab">                      
        @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Item/_Tabs.cshtml", tabsForItem );}
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CatID` isn't a Javascript variable... it's a c# variable that needs to be rendered into the page. Using Razor syntax, this would be:

```
onclick="LoadCategoryData(@CatID, this.href)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to put an @ sign in front of CatID when you send it in the onclick function.

It should be:

```
   onclick="LoadCategoryData(@CatID, this.href)"
```

Comment: Thank you, but can't accept yours since spender's answer was the first one, and was a little more explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

First `<img>` don't have a property `href`. Are you trying to add the click handler to `<a>`?

I personally don't suggest you mix javascript in html element like you did. You should use unobtrusive javascript.

You could try something like this,

```
<img id=".img" border="0" src="view_cat.png" alt ="Up" title="Go To This Category" 
          width="10" height="10" data-catid="@CatID" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".img").click(function(){
     LoadCategoryData($(this).data("catid"), $(this).attr("src"));
  });
</script>
```

Now you can put this script in a separate file.

Comment: You're right, I have already fixed it with a little help from [this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202619/get-href-attribute-of-enclosing-link-tag). Will clean up rest of the code, thanks.