# oneliner-javascript: render parent tag's attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="Blah">
  <h2>Blubb</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
</div>
```

For testing purposes I need a one-liner js that renders the "Blah" inside the h2 like here:

```
<div id="Blah">
  <h2>Blubb (Blah)</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
</div>
```

I know it would be easy with jquery, but I am absolute beginner with JS / JQuery...

seems the same like here: [get href attribute of enclosing link tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202619/get-href-attribute-of-enclosing-link-tag)

**But I do not know how to call it in my html. Please add minial complete html-file, not only jquery snippets...**

Comment: The link is something different. You want to just place text inside the `h2` right? How would you do it in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('div.myclass > h2').text(function (_, text) {
        return text + " (" + $(this).parent().attr('myattr') + ")";
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sez7c/)

Comment: nice, how would I select the divs based on a css class ?

Comment: how would I use an arbitrary (self-defined) attribute instead of id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("h2").text($("h2").text()+" (Blah)");
//or if you want div "Blah" id set as append text then 

$("h2").text($("h2").text()+" ("+$(this).closest("#Blah").attr('id')+")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dRcn2/)</kbd>

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#Blah h2').text(function (_, old) {
        return old + '(' + $(this).parent().attr('id') + ')';
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('h2:contains("Blubb")').text();
$('h2:contains("Blubb")').text(a+' (Blah)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
$h2 = $('div > h2');
$h2.append(' ('+$h2[0].parentNode.id+')');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FMXS8/)